# How can I to keep chat with sticky footer in view at all times?

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I want to implement a chat which stays in screen with a sticky footer, but I'm really stuck. Here's what I would like:

[image]

Or at least, have the bottom of my chat at the bottom of the content or screen.
I'm using Bootstrap 4.1.

I tried to represent you an example of what I have here: [Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5hkwtb)

The chat sticks to the top like what I want, but because of the navbar it don't stick to the bottom.

Comment: Please post a code sample of what you're working with. You can do that with regular CSS, it's not something that you need to use flexbox for. Bootstrap has a sticky footer component already setup for you. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/examples/sticky-footer/

Comment: Yes i have the sticky-footer, the problem is just for the chat. Can't keep at the bottom of the screen if content is higher than screen

Comment: Please create a code snippet that you can share with the problem, https://stackblitz.com is an easy place to copy/paste your code over to share. Happy to help troubleshoot but need more to go on.

Comment: I made something similar here: https://codepen.io/IvanS95/pen/zeBRRP maybe that's what you're looking for, let me know (I omitted some of the styling, just wanted to show the general structure)

Comment: Actually an off-site code sandbox is not adequate; if you have a question about code that doesn't work the way you want it to, the [mcve] needs to be included *in the question itself*, not just linked in the question.

Comment: @TylerH, I updated the code in the original post

Comment: @CWSites We rely on the OP to include the [mcve] for various reasons, typically.

Comment: I understand, just trying to be helpful. New users don't always understand or do a good job of it.

Comment: Sorry guys, if my request was ... a little crappy. Next time, I'll do better.

Answer (score 2):

**Better view this snippet in full screen**

This is something I made a while ago and I think is kinda what you're looking for; It is a lot of code mostly because of the markup since it was a whole component, but maybe it can help you getting on the right track.

I use **Flexbox** and **Bootstrap 4** to adjust everything as well as making some calculations with CSS, but the main idea is to create containers that each handle their content and overflows independently. You would need to define a `height` so the components remain in place without being pushed. Let me know if this is what you intend to do; maybe we can work based on this.

```css
#messages-section {
  min-height: inherit;
}

#messages-section>div {
  min-height: inherit;
}

.messages-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: inherit;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.messages-container .contacts-box {
  width: 340px;
}

.messages-container .contacts-box .contacts-list {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}

.messages-container .contacts-box .contacts-list .contact {
  min-height: 96px;
  border-top: 0.5px solid #efefef;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #efefef;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  color: #363636;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.messages-container .contacts-box .contacts-list .contact.new-messages {
  background-color: #f3f6f9;
}

.messages-container .contacts-box .contacts-list .contact:hover {
  background-color: #f3f6f9;
}

.messages-container .contacts-box .contacts-list .contact:active {
  background-color: rgba(249, 92, 144, 0.096);
}

.messages-container .contacts-box .contacts-list .contact .avatar {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.messages-container .contacts-box .contacts-list .contact .contact-info {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.messages-container .contacts-box .contacts-list .contact .contact-info p {
  font-size: 12px;
  max-height: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.messages-container .contacts-box .contacts-list .contact .timer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 10px;
}

.messages-container .contacts-box .contacts-list .contact .timer span {
  font-size: 11px;
  user-select: none;
}

.messages-container .message-box {
  width: calc(100% - 340px);
}

.messages-container .message-box .conversation-panel {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  border-right: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.messages-container .message-box .conversation {
  border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
  height: calc(100vh - 170px);
  padding: 16px 40px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.messages-container .message-box .conversation .message-card {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.messages-container .message-box .conversation .message-card:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.messages-container .message-box .conversation .message-card .avatar {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.messages-container .message-box .conversation .message-card .message-text {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.messages-container .message-box .conversation .message-card .message-text:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.messages-container .message-box .conversation .message-card.user-message {
  background-color: #f3f6f9;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.messages-container .message-box .conversation .message-card.user-message .avatar {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.messages-container .message-box .conversation .message-card.user-message .message-text {
  text-align: right;
}

.messages-container .message-box .conversation .message-card.contact-message {
  background-color: rgba(249, 92, 144, 0.06);
}

.messages-container .message-box .conversation .message-card.contact-message .avatar {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.messages-container .message-box .writing-panel {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #f3f6f9;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.messages-container .message-box .writing-panel button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.messages-container .message-box .writing-panel button:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.messages-container .message-box .writing-panel button:hover svg {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.messages-container .message-box .writing-panel button:hover svg path {
  fill: #de008f;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.messages-container .message-box .writing-panel textarea {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 1px 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.messages-container .message-box .writing-panel textarea:focus {
  border-color: #de008f;
}

.messages-container .messages-header {
  height: 70px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.messages-container .messages-header.contacts-header {
  border-left: 0px solid #efefef;
  border-top: 2px solid #efefef;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.messages-container .messages-header.contacts-header button {
  width: 25px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: url(../assets/img/msg/new-msg.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 90%;
  background-position: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.messages-container .messages-header.contacts-header button:active {
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border: none;
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
}

.messages-container .messages-header.contacts-header .input-group .input-group-text {
  background: none;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.messages-container .messages-header.contacts-header .input-group .form-control {
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.messages-container .messages-header.conversation-header {
  border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-top: 2px solid #efefef;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-right: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.messages-container .messages-header.conversation-header .message-title h5 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
}

.messages-container .messages-header.conversation-header .message-title .status-info.online {
  color: #04d2af;
}

.messages-container .messages-header.conversation-header .message-title .status-info.offline {
  color: #ff1e1e;
}

.messages-container .messages-header.conversation-header .call-icon,
.messages-container .messages-header.conversation-header .menu-icon {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.messages-container .messages-header.conversation-header .call-icon:hover .a,
.messages-container .messages-header.conversation-header .menu-icon:hover .a {
  fill: #de008f;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.messages-container .messages-header.conversation-header .call-icon:active,
.messages-container .messages-header.conversation-header .menu-icon:active {
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="section p-0" id="messages-section">
  <div class="">
    <div id="message-window" class="messages-container">
      <div class="contacts-box">
        <header class="messages-header contacts-header">

          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 17.49 17.49"><defs><style>.a{fill:#363636;}</style></defs><path class="a" d="M15.5,14h-.79l-.28-.27a6.51,6.51,0,1,0-.7.7l.27.28v.79l5,4.99L20.49,19Zm-6,0A4.5,4.5,0,1,1,14,9.5,4.494,4.494,0,0,1,9.5,14Z" transform="translate(-3 -3)"/></svg>
                                            </span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by User" aria-label="Search by User" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon2"></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>

        <div id="contact-list" class="contacts-list">
          <div class="contact new-messages" id="contact-item-1">
            <div class="avatar">
              <div class="avatar-container">
                <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                  <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="contact-info">
              <h5>Grant Marshall</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, dolor ex aliquam commodi ab incidunt.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="timer">
              <span>15 min</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contact" id="contact-item-2">
            <div class="avatar">
              <div class="avatar-container">
                <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                  <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="contact-info">
              <h5>Jessica Miles</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, dolor ex aliquam commodi ab incidunt.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="timer">
              <span>15 min</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contact" id="contact-item-3">
            <div class="avatar">
              <div class="avatar-container">
                <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                  <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="contact-info">
              <h5>Natasha Gamble</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, dolor ex aliquam commodi ab incidunt.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="timer">
              <span>15 min</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contact" id="contact-item-4">
            <div class="avatar">
              <div class="avatar-container">
                <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                  <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="contact-info">
              <h5>Vanessa Ryan</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, dolor ex aliquam commodi ab incidunt.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="timer">
              <span>15 min</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contact new-messages" id="contact-item-5">
            <div class="avatar">
              <div class="avatar-container">
                <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                  <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="contact-info">
              <h5>Carol Kelly</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, dolor ex aliquam commodi ab incidunt.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="timer">
              <span>15 min</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contact" id="contact-item-6">
            <div class="avatar">
              <div class="avatar-container">
                <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                  <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="contact-info">
              <h5>Julia Petersen</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, dolor ex aliquam commodi ab incidunt.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="timer">
              <span>15 min</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contact" id="contact-item-7">
            <div class="avatar">
              <div class="avatar-container">
                <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                  <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="contact-info">
              <h5>Marisa Cain</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, dolor ex aliquam commodi ab incidunt.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="timer">
              <span>15 min</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contact" id="contact-item-8">
            <div class="avatar">
              <div class="avatar-container">
                <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                  <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="contact-info">
              <h5>Gayle Gaines</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, dolor ex aliquam commodi ab incidunt.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="timer">
              <span>15 min</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contact" id="contact-item-9">
            <div class="avatar">
              <div class="avatar-container">
                <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                  <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="contact-info">
              <h5>Keri Hudson</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, dolor ex aliquam commodi ab incidunt.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="timer">
              <span>15 min</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="message-box">
        <header class="messages-header conversation-header">
          <button class="call-icon">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><defs><style>.a{fill:#363636;}</style></defs><path class="a" d="M6.62,10.79a15.149,15.149,0,0,0,6.59,6.59l2.2-2.2a.994.994,0,0,1,1.02-.24,11.407,11.407,0,0,0,3.57.57,1,1,0,0,1,1,1V20a1,1,0,0,1-1,1A17,17,0,0,1,3,4,1,1,0,0,1,4,3H7.5a1,1,0,0,1,1,1,11.36,11.36,0,0,0,.57,3.57,1,1,0,0,1-.25,1.02Z" transform="translate(-3 -3)"/></svg>
                                    </button>
          <div class="text-center message-title">
            <h5>Jessica Miles</h5>
            <span class="status-info online">online</span>
          </div>
          <button id="message-back" class="menu-icon">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 21 5"><defs><style>.a{fill:#363636;}</style></defs><g transform="translate(-1084 -136)"><circle class="a" cx="2.5" cy="2.5" r="2.5" transform="translate(1084 136)"/><circle class="a" cx="2.5" cy="2.5" r="2.5" transform="translate(1092 136)"/><circle class="a" cx="2.5" cy="2.5" r="2.5" transform="translate(1100 136)"/></g></svg>
                                    </button>
        </header>

        <div class="conversation-panel">
          <div class="conversation">
            <div class="message-card contact-message">
              <div class="avatar">
                <div class="avatar-container">
                  <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                    <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perferendis esse sapiente vitae dignissimos temporibus</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message-card user-message">
              <div class="avatar">
                <div class="avatar-container">
                  <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                    <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message-card contact-message">
              <div class="avatar">
                <div class="avatar-container">
                  <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                    <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perferendis esse sapiente vitae dignissimos temporibus. Placeat voluptates commodi quia enim minima quibusdam ducimus tempora quod ut error dolor, eligendi nihil iusto.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message-card user-message">
              <div class="avatar">
                <div class="avatar-container">
                  <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                    <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perferendis esse sapiente vitae dignissimos temporibus. Placeat voluptates commodi quia enim minima quibusdam ducimus tempora quod ut error dolor, eligendi nihil iusto.</p>
                <p class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perferendis esse sapiente vitae dignissimos temporibus. Placeat voluptates commodi quia enim minima quibusdam ducimus tempora quod ut error dolor, eligendi nihil iusto.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message-card contact-message">
              <div class="avatar">
                <div class="avatar-container">
                  <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                    <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perferendis esse sapiente vitae dignissimos temporibus. Placeat voluptates commodi quia enim minima quibusdam ducimus tempora quod ut error dolor, eligendi nihil iusto.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message-card user-message">
              <div class="avatar">
                <div class="avatar-container">
                  <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                    <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perferendis esse sapiente vitae dignissimos temporibus. Placeat voluptates commodi quia enim minima quibusdam ducimus tempora quod ut error dolor, eligendi nihil iusto.</p>
                <p class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perferendis esse sapiente vitae dignissimos temporibus. Placeat voluptates commodi quia enim minima quibusdam ducimus tempora quod ut error dolor, eligendi nihil iusto.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message-card contact-message">
              <div class="avatar">
                <div class="avatar-container">
                  <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                    <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perferendis esse sapiente vitae dignissimos temporibus. Placeat voluptates commodi quia enim minima quibusdam ducimus tempora quod ut error dolor, eligendi nihil iusto.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message-card user-message">
              <div class="avatar">
                <div class="avatar-container">
                  <div class="avatar-photo-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="avatar-img user-badge-photo" alt="avatar photo">
                    <img src="../assets/img/green-stat.svg" width="8" class="avatar-status" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perferendis esse sapiente vitae dignissimos temporibus. Placeat voluptates commodi quia enim minima quibusdam ducimus tempora quod ut error dolor, eligendi nihil iusto.</p>
                <p class="message-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Perferendis esse sapiente vitae dignissimos temporibus. Placeat voluptates commodi quia enim minima quibusdam ducimus tempora quod ut error dolor, eligendi nihil iusto.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="writing-panel d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <textarea class="mx-2 mx-md-3" name="message-text" placeholder="Type your message" id="" rows="1"></textarea>
            <button class="send-btn">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 30.925 26.049"><defs><style>.a{opacity:1;}.b{fill:#616161;}</style></defs><g class="a" transform="translate(0.006)"><path class="b" d="M27.75,2.89,18.65,21.1,3.47,11.24,27.75,2.89M29.97,0a1.115,1.115,0,0,0-.31.05L.64,10.03a.955.955,0,0,0-.64.78.965.965,0,0,0,.43.92L18.21,23.29a1.34,1.34,0,0,0,.72.21,1.06,1.06,0,0,0,.35-.05,1.344,1.344,0,0,0,.84-.69L30.82,1.38A.943.943,0,0,0,30.68.33.938.938,0,0,0,29.97,0Z"/><path class="b" d="M12.31,18.66c-1.73-.85-1.11-1.79-1.11-1.79s7.11-6.14,9.54-8.44a.242.242,0,0,0,.03-.31.352.352,0,0,0-.38-.09L4.83,14V25.09a1.054,1.054,0,0,0,1.71.72l7.24-6.29A13.444,13.444,0,0,0,12.31,18.66Z"/></g></svg>
                                        </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks IvanS95, it's almost this, but not exactly. I will try to use it to achieve what i need

Comment: @LaSmala Sure, based on what you shared I think you still need to define a `height` to your chat container, so that it doesn't go bigger than the screen, something like `max-height: calc(100vh - 100px)` to compensate for the space to `header` and `footer` take up